# Accessing the contents of a selected subclasses UITableViewCell

Tags: ios

If I've subclass `UITableViewCell` with say `MySubclassedCell` and it contains a few labels and an image, how would I go about accessing the contents of the subclassed cell in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method?

Normally (without subclassing) I'd do this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

and then go from there. Replacing `MySubclassedCell` doesn't work, so what if I need to access the properties of a subclassed cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't quite understand you when you say replacing MySubclassedCell doesn't work, can't you just do this -

```
 MySubclassedCell *cell = (MySubclassedCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Comment: I mean't replacing `UITableViewCell` with `MySubclassedCell` doesn't work and gives an error for 'incompatible pointer types' because `cellForRowAtIndexPath` returns a `UITableViewCell` object.